# Implementing a hash table in C with strange seg fault

Tags: c, linked-list, hashmap, malloc, hashtable

I'm trying to make a hashtable in C and I'd like to record a linked list that contains each unique key of the table. However, I'm getting a seg fault at the very start of the while loop that I use to to check if a key is already in the linked list. Can anyone understand what is going on here?

APOLOGIES IN ADVANCE: ull is unsigned long long

h_keys is a global variable,

The seg fault occurs at the start of this while loop.

```
void put_in_key(ull address){
    struct mem_node * cur = h_keys;
    ull key = hash_func(address);
    printf("ok %lld\n",address);
    while(cur){
        //printf("stuck in here?\n");
        if(cur->key==key){ // key already in hashtable keys
            return;
        }
        cur=cur->next;
    }
    struct mem_node* newkey = malloc(sizeof(struct mem_node *));
    if(newkey==NULL){
        printf("big trouble");
    }
    newkey->key=key;
    cur->next=newkey;
}
```

here is the struct

```
struct mem_node{ // add one of these each time we get a new window
    ull address;
    ull page;
    ull key;
    struct mem_node * next;
};
```

here is the declaration of h_keys

```
h_keys=malloc(sizeof(struct mem_node*));
```

and then depending on the input I sometimes reach a part of this other function that counts the length of the linkedlist. However, I get a segfault at the 1st line of the while loop here as well.

```
struct mem_node* counter = h_keys;
        ull uniques=0;
        while(counter!=NULL && counter->next!=NULL){
            printf("whafs da %lld\n",uniques);
        
            //printf("%lld\n",counter->key);
            //printf("%lld \n",counter->ne)
            fflush(stdout);
            uniques++;
            counter=counter->next;
        }
```

Comment: Code is too incomplete. Please provide complete code as a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). One thing that looks wrong: `malloc(sizeof(struct mem_node*))` should be `malloc(sizeof(struct mem_node))`;

Comment: BTW, using a linked list to implement a hash table is odd if not outright wrong. The point of a hash table is that it allows you to jump straight to a node that matches the key hash. Traversing a list should only be needed for collisions (nodes with same hash but different data values). Usually hash tables are implemented with arrays.

Comment: @kaylum I'm using the linkedlist to keep track of the keys of the hashtable, sort of like a dic.keys() method in python. Because I need to do a count of the total number of keys that are mapped to something that isn't null

Comment: *I need to do a count of the total number of keys*. If that's all you need then you should keep a running count every time a new key is added or removed. Anyway, the main point is that your code is incomplete so we can't help effectively and your allocation size looks wrong. Please provide complete code.

Comment: @kaylum Ok I'm going to try that approach and skip the linked list thing. Thank you!